# No anti-aliasing with Xmonad

Tags: fonts, xmonad, antialiasing

I'm looking into Xmonad. One problem I'm having is that most of my applications in Xmonad don't have anti-aliasing.

For example gnome-terminal & evolution. I have this in my .Xresources:

```
Xft.dpi: 96
Xft.lcdfilter: lcddefault
Xft.antialias: true
Xft.autohint: true
Xft.hinting: true
Xft.hintstyle: hintfull
Xft.hintstyle: slight
Xft.rgba: rgb
```

And this in my .gtkrc-2.0:

```
gtk-theme-name="Ambiance"
gtk-icon-theme-name="ubuntu-mono-dark"
gtk-font-name="Sans 10"
gtk-cursor-theme-name="DMZ-White"
gtk-cursor-theme-size=0
gtk-toolbar-style=GTK_TOOLBAR_BOTH
gtk-toolbar-icon-size=GTK_ICON_SIZE_LARGE_TOOLBAR
gtk-button-images=1
gtk-menu-images=1
gtk-enable-event-sounds=1
gtk-enable-input-feedback-sounds=1
gtk-xft-antialias=1
gtk-xft-hinting=1
gtk-xft-hintstyle="hintfull"
gtk-xft-rgba="rgb"
include "/home/leon/.gtkrc-2.0.mine"
```

But I still have no anti-aliasing. When I launch gnome-settings-daemon I do get anti-aliasing. But I don't want to run gnome-settings-daemon.

What could be the problem? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop.

Answer (score 4):

You have conflicting directives in your .Xresources. Try removing one of the two lines:

```
Xft.hintstyle: hintfull
Xft.hintstyle: slight
```

And see if that works. I used exactly your .gtkrc-2.0 and .Xresources on a relatively unmodified Xmonad setup on Ubuntu 12.04, and the setting worked correctly once I removed one of those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this to make sure that your .Xresources changes are getting applied?

```
xrdb -merge .Xresources
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. In the meantime I also rebooted several times and that didn't work either.

Comment: Next question: what video hardware do you have and which drivers are you using? The reason I ask is to determine how closely your setup matches mine so we can start eliminating variables.

Comment: I don't think it's something with the hardware. Every other wm behaves correctly. But for completeness: I have a Sandy Bridge/optimus (?) with bumblbee installed. The Intel driver is the default one: i915 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `gnome-settings-daemon` is running.